# Sublime Text 2 highlighting always disabled on trailing spaces plugin

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

In Sublime Text 2 I have installed the trailing spaces plugin, however the highlighting is always set to disabled.

if I toggle the highlight regions, by doing the following:

`edit -> trailing spaces -> highlight regions`

I always get the following:

> highlighting of trailing spaces is disabled!

I have restarted sublime since the package install, but the toggle doesn't seem to work, does anyone know how to fix this issue?

**Work around fix - not the solution to the problem**

As for others it seems, i couldn't seem to get this trailing spaces to highlight no matter what i did, so what i did was remove the trailing spaces automatically on save. Not ideal but used to it now, works nicely.

Go to **SublimeText 2** > **Preferences** > **User Settings** (or just hit the Mac Standard <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>). This should open your User Settings as a JSON file. Add the following to your file

`"trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true`

That's it. You're good to go.

Comment: Can you edit your question to display a link to the plugin you're using? I suspect it's [this one](https://github.com/SublimeText/TrailingSpaces), but we can't really help you unless we know for certain.

Comment: I have the same issue and yes, it is the one here: https://github.com/SublimeText/TrailingSpaces. Every time you click toggle is just says "highlighting of trailing spaces is disabled!". Like, you cannot enable it.

Comment: yep pezzi is correct, seems a very strange issue, i have a work around for now but would like to find the cause for the issue.

Comment: **Workaround (not fix):** Set Edit -> Trailing Spaces -> Highlight Regions to "off" and then CMD + Shift + P and "Toggle Trailing Spaced Highlighting" and restart Sublime. Seems like the menu options are colliding with the Command Palette.

Comment: I have the same issue. carlcalderon's workaround didn't work for me. Reinstalling the plugin also doesn't fix the problem. Been working fine until today.

Comment: @LewisJackson try the workout i posted in the edit above, may help.

Comment: I fixed it for my situation, see my answer below. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: @gardni: The only answer worked for me. Maybe you could accept it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had this problem in Sublime Text 3.

I fixed it by deleting my `trailing_spaces.sublime-settings` file in the Sublime Text user package settings folder (which for me was `%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User`) and reinstalling the plugin.

Some more discussion about this issue can be found on the plugin GitHub page [here](https://github.com/SublimeText/TrailingSpaces/issues/46).

Comment: That did it for me, too!

Comment: In Sublime Text 2, I didn't need to reinstall the package for the fix to work. Closing Sublime and deleting `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/trailing_spaces.sublime-settings` was enough to do the trick.

Answer (score 11):

It's a known bug - see their [Issues](https://github.com/SublimeText/TrailingSpaces/issues) page on GitHub.

I was able to get it working by starting Sublime with a non-blank string value for the setting `trailing_spaces_highlight_color`

1. Open `Preferences > Package Settings > Trailing Spaces > Settings - User`
2. Replace:
   `"trailing_spaces_highlight_color": ""`

   With:
   `"trailing_spaces_highlight_color": "invalid"`
3. Restart Sublime.
4. `Edit > Trailing Spaces > Highlight Regions` should work as expected now.

If you restart Sublime, `"trailing_spaces_highlight_color"` must not be a blank string, otherwise it will stop working again. Repeat the steps above to fix.

As long as Sublime is started with a non-blank string value for `trailing_spaces_highlight_color`, the toggle highlight regions works.

It looks like the plugin is caching the value in the setting file when Sublime loads. If you make changes to the settings file and toggle highlighting, the original value is restored. Which is why you need to restart Sublime for setting changes to take effect.

Comment: This worked for me. I believe this should be the accepted answer.